# How can I set a comma separator for thousands as a default option for how the interpreter in R presents numbers?

Tags: r

I dont want a function. I just want to have that be the default way in which the R interpreter always displays numbers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not aware of a way to have your numbers always display with commas, there is a way to turn-off scientific notation for your session and then format your numerical output to show commas as a string.

Here's one possible solution:

```
# Load library
load(scales)

# Turn-off scientific notation for your R session
options(scipen = 999)
  
# An example vector of big numbers  
x = c(1000000000000000, 2000000000000, 3000000000000)

# Use the scales::comma() function to add commas
# Output will be formated as a string
comma(x)
#> [1] "1,000,000,000,000,000" "2,000,000,000,000"     "3,000,000,000,000"
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your answer.